# Checking and submitting form via Ajax in boostrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a login form in boostrap's modal window

```
<form method="post" id="loginForm" action="index.php">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" value="" id="emailLogin"/><br/>

  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" value="" id="passwordLogin"/><br/>
  <div id="loginAlert" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Email or password incorrect</div> <!-- Hidden by default -->

  <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary" id="loginButton">Login</button>
  <script src="checkLoginForm.js"></script></form>
```

I would like to check this form (if email and password are correct) before submitting it. If the function, which checks the email and password returns 1, there is something incorrect. Form should not submit in this case and it should just make the alert visible.
If everything is correct, it should submit.

Thing is: I can prevent the form from submitting, if the the email and password are incorrect, but I can't submit it, if they are correct. Here is the code from `checkLoginForm.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loginForm").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'include/ajax.php?action=checkLogin',
            data: {
                email: $("#emailLogin").val(),
                password: $("#passwordLogin").val(),
            },
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                if(result == 0) {

                } else {
                    $("#loginAlert").css({"display": "block"});
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I have no idea what to do, when the result == 0. If I do `$("loginForm").submit();`, that does not submit the form (else part does work).

Thank you for your replies.

Comment: You're missing `#`, it should be `$("#loginForm").submit();`

Comment: Sorry about that, just a typo when writing the post. `#` is there - does not work.

Comment: @Denco just submit the form and check if the provided information is correct in your php file. If not return 0 or false to your JS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice you to use a simple `$.post`, it's a shorthand way of using `$.ajax` for POST requests. Just check if the values provided are correct in your php file, if they are correct process that data and return true or redirect the user to another page else return false.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loginButton").on('click', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var email = $("#emailLogin").val();
        var passwd = $("#passwordLogin").val();
        $.post('include/ajax.php?action=checkLogin', {email: email, password: passwd}, function (data) {
            var res = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (res.result == true) {
                //you can redirect the or display a message to the user.
                //redirect the user to another page
                //$("#loginAlert").css({"display": "block"}).html("login successful");
            }else {
                $("#loginAlert").css({"display": "block"});
            }
        });
    });
  });
```

Then in your php file

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'checkLogin') {
    $passwd = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $email = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
    //validate inputs here
    //get data from db
    //then compare values
    //if values match return true
    //$db_mail and $db_passwd are from the db.
    if ($email == $db_mail && $passwd == $db_passwd) {
        //if the provided information is correct
        //process it here, login the user.
        //redirect if necessary.
        // or return results to JS 
        echo json_encode(['result' => true]);
    } else {
        //if the information is wrong return false to JS
        //and alert the user
        echo json_encode(['result' => false]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did not do it exactly like your example, but your answer helped me to get my code working. Thank you.